# How to mock ExecuteUpdateAsync method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nunit, masstransit

How to write unit test case for ExecuteUpdateAsync in EF Core 7.0.

For example like GetAll method we can mock as below. Can i mock executeupdateasync method.

repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(employees)

I have searched for this on stackoverlow for an example but have not got a clue on this.

await context.Blogs.ExecuteUpdateAsync(
s => s.SetProperty(b => b.Name, b => b.Name + " *Featured!*"));

Comment: Any clue on this

Comment: This currently does not work when using In Memory db. You'll either need to go the old EF Core route to update or ignore the unit test for now.